# How to VLOOKUP get #N/A value in VBA?

Tags: excel, error-handling, vlookup, vba

I have a data table in Excel, that is same as:

```
    A       B
-------------
1. aaa     11
2. bbb     22
3. ccc     #N/A
4. ddd     44
```

I've wrote a VBA function to get value(col B) by key(in col A)
Ex: `=getValue(A1)`

In this example, if I type `=getValue(A3)`, function is throw #VALUE! error. I was debug and see error at VLOOKUP function. Here is my code:

```
Public Function getValue(ByVal key As Variant)

    'get value of the cell at column B which has value 'key' at column A on same row
    column2GetValue = 2
    useClosestMatch = False

    'error here if colum2GetValue contain #N/A
    found = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup( _
        key, _
        Worksheets(SHEET_CACHE_NAME).Range("A:B"), _
        column2GetValue, _
        useClosestMatch _
    )

    getValue = found
End Function
```

**How to VLOOKUP get #N/A value in VBA?**
Thank for your help!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can handle the error as below.

Although I suggest you look consider using a more versatile `Find` in place of `Application.VLOOKUP`

```
Sub TestMe()
Dim vTest As Variant
vTest = Application.VLookup("TesT", Range("A1:B10"), 2, False)
If IsError(vTest) Then
MsgBox "Not found", vbCritical
Else
MsgBox "value is " & vTest
End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Oh, I tried with IsError in my function, but function crash then exit  at the line `Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup` when `column2GetValue` contain `#N/A`; the function cannot go to the `IsError` below

Comment: Remove the `WorksheetFunction`